# 403 forbidden error when using requests even with setting the header to {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} on curseforge

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, http-status-code-403

When trying to access Curse Forge to get data on how many downloads i have, despite setting the headers i still get a 403 error. I have a suspicion that it has to do with cookies but there is a monstrous amount of cookies for the website. Another option is CAPTCHA but these are just guesses i need to know specifically what is going wrong and a workaround for it.

Heres just the basic response getter:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

response = session.get('https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/machine-built-world', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: 403 is authorization error. Is the data behind a login?If so, then you have to login with your python code first, store the cookies and session and then you would be able to get the data you're looking for.

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 is most likely not enough to get past actual User-Agent filters. Try to put a full user agent. for example you can go to https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=user+agent&ia=answer and copy your own user agent.